# Unzipping results in a file, not a folder

Tags: linux, zip

I zipped 6 files (total size = 2gb) using `gzip -c myfiles_* > ~/myzip.gzip` on server A and got my friend to copy this server to server B. Now I've learned that the file is supposed to be named `.gz` so I renamed the file using `mv`. I checked that the file on server B had the same size as the original `.gzip` file on server A, which it did. Then I ran `gunzip myzip.gz`.

The result is not a folder containing my files, but a single file named `myfiles` without any extension. The size of the file is the same size as the initial files so all of the files have been compiled into this single file. How do I now extract the files again from this single file?

As you can tell I am still very new to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I zipped 6 files (total size = 2gb) using `gzip -c myfiles_* >
>   ~/myzip.gzip` and got my friend to copy this server to another server.
>   Now I've learned that the archive is supposed to be named `.gz` so I
>   renamed the file using `mv`. Then I ran `gunzip myzip.gz`.

The results you are seeing is exactly what you created. GZip does not retain any directory structure when it compresses; it just compresses files/data. So when you ran this command:

```
gzip -c myfiles_* > ~/myzip.gzip
```

All GZip did was concatenate all of the files it found with `myfiles_*` into one big blob and compress them into `~/myzip.gzip`. The fact the file extension is incorrect is irrelevant since just renaming that file—like you did—would solve the problem but the underlying archive is still just one big blob of files.

As for how to recover that now? Pretty confident you cannot because the problem was in your initial GZip logic.  The only recommendation I would have for you now is to start back at square one and create a TAR/GZipped archive like this.

#### Creating the TAR/GZipped file.

First, run this TAR command:

```
tar -cf myzip.tar myfiles_*
```

That would create a new TAR archive named `myzip.tar` that consists of the files the system found by using the pattern, `myfiles_*`.

Now with that done, you can GZip that TAR archive like this:

```
gzip myzip.tar
```

This is my process of handling this stuff in Mac OS X, but if you are using a GNU version of TAR—which most Linux systems use—you could run this command to combine both steps into one instead:

```
tar -cfz myzip.tar.gz
```

Note that extra `z` in the options? That tells TAR to GZip the archive when creating it.

#### Decompressing and unarchiving the TAR/GZipped file.

Once that is done, you will have a new archive that is named `myzip.tar.gz`. Transfer that whatever place you need it to be and then decompress it using the TAR command like this:

```
tar -xf myzip.tar.gz
```

TAR is smart enough nowadays to detect GZip compression as a part of its unarchiving process, so it will decompress the TAR archive and then extract the contents of that TAR archive back in place to exactly match the file and directory structure of whatever the source was to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The new file has no extensions and I'm quite certain the file was simply copied using the `scp` command I sent to him, which only contained the two paths.

Comment: I hate Linux some times.. Seems like there's no other way, thanks.